# Python dice game

Tags: python

I must create a dice game that generates numbers from 1 to 6. It will then throw the dice 50 times and it will count the number of odd numbers and even numbers. I'm using Python.

Here is my code:

```
import random

# Determine odd and even numbers

throws = 0
even = 0
odd = 0
maxthrows = 50

print "Even : Odd"

while True:
    throws += 1
    if throws == maxthrows:
        break

dice = random.randrange(6)

if dice % 2 == 1:
    odd += 1
else:
    even += 1
print even, " : ", odd

raw_input("Press enter to exit.")
```

Comment: What does not work? Which error is thrown?

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question :-)

Comment: what the `raw_input` is for here? You should also put all that code in a function, and call that function after a `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard. And BTW, what is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop is wrong, it should be:

```
while throws != maxthrows:
    throws += 1
    dice = random.randrange(6)
    if dice % 2 == 1:
        odd += 1
    else:
        even += 1
```

Notice that:

- Whenever possible, the exit condition should be used in the loop condition, not in an `if ... break`
- The part where you ask if the dice is odd must be *inside* the loop, in Python indentation matters - a lot!